# 404 on acme-challenge for nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx backend server that has a Let's Encrypt certificate.  Now, I want to add an Nginx reverse proxy and create a Let's Encrypt certificate for it.  When I try to reach http://jcp-connect.fr/.well-known/acme-challenge/test, It returns a 404 status.

Firstly, I created a webroot:

- `mkdir -p /var/www/jcp/.well-known/acme-challenge`
- Create file to test
- `echo "nginx is awesome!" > /var/www/jcp/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html`

In my Nginx proxy configuration file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse I set the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name jcp-connect.fr;
  index index.htm index.html;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  location / {
     try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @backend;
  }
  location @backend {

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://jcp-connect.fr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 900s;
  }
}
```

My Nginx backend server has an IP@ 192.168.1.45 and it is in another different host.

Comment: `/var/www/jcp` is not `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but this is a typos I forgot to modify it only in this post only but in my code it's ok :
mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge 
Create file to test echo 
"nginx is awesome!" > /usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html